# Javascript - How to clone an object?

Tags: javascript, copy, clone

I am confused. I create a copy from `myObjOne`, than i delete an entry from `myObjOne` and JS delete the entry in my copy(`myObjTwo`) too? But why?

```
  myObjOne = {};
  myObjOne['name'] = 'xxx';
  myObjOne['id'] = 'yyy';
  myObjOne['plz'] = 'zzz';  

  // clone
  myObjTwo = myObjOne;

  // remove something
  delete myObjOne['name'];

  console.dir(myObjTwo);
```

**example**
http://jsbin.com/itixes/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying an Object in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Update: Removing `Object.create` as a method of cloning as indicated in comments.

```
  myObjTwo = myObjOne;
```

does not clone. It simply copies the reference.

If you want to clone, you can use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`

```
var x = {a:{b:{c:{'d':'e'}}}};
var y = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(x));  //y is a clone of x
console.log(y.a.b.c.d); //prints e
console.log(y === x); //prints false
```

**Warning:** As Raynos mentioned in comments, this JSON based clone does not retain methods of the input object in the output object. This solution is good enough if your object does not contain any methods. Methods are properties of a object that are functions. If `var obj = {add : function(a,b){return a+b;}}` then `add` is a method of `obj`.

If you need a solution that supports copying of methods, then go through these SO answers (as pointed out by musefan, Matt and Ranhiru Cooray)

- [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript)
- [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

I would suggest [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript/728694#728694)

Comment: a={name:1};b=Object.create(a);delete a.name; Now b doesn't have 'name' property either

Comment: `Object.create` does not make a clone but adds `x` to the prototype chain of `y`.

Comment: @pimvdb , spicavigo Thanks for pointing out. Removed `Object.create`.

Comment: Using JSON to clone is expensive as hell and destroys methods.

Comment: @Raynos Please feel free to update my answer if you wish to include a faster method. I think for simple objects, it is fast enough and concise. I also checked the jsperf http://jsperf.com/clone/2 before posting and it looks comparable. In any case please feel free to update.

Comment: @Narendra a shallow property wise clone is [easy](https://github.com/Raynos/pd#pd.extend). A deep clone is a nightmare. JSON is a sensible solution, you just forgot to mention its limitations

Answer (score 16):

You can use jQuery like so:

```
var myObjTwo = jQuery.extend(true, {}, myObjOne);
```

The first argument indicates that we want to make a deep copy of `myObjOne`.

Answer (score 4):

That is not how you clone, that is simply storing the same original object in an extra variable. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/copying-an-object-in-javascript) will help you

Answer (score 2):

Lots of advice on how to make a copy not only of the object and it's properties, but of all the objects referenced by its properties. Here's a version that clones the object without copying it and so that the clone inherits all properties added later except for those shadowed by own properties of the clone:

```
var cloneOf = (function() {
  function F(){}
  return function(o) {
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
  }
}());
```

Some may recognise the pattern. An example:

```
var base = {foo:'foo', bar:'bar'};
var baseClone = cloneOf(base);
alert(baseClone.foo);  // foo
```

Comment: Why you use the prototype chain rather then copying properties over?

Comment: Because it is one way to "clone" an object - the OP didn't say what was expected of the clone, so anything goes.

Comment: This works quite well. It works on objects with multiple nested objects/children and also functions. After you cloned the object, you can delete the "original", and the clone will be intact.

Answer (score 2):

With ES6, use the spread operator.

```
myObjTwo = {...myObjOne}
```

The spread operator in es6 is just an ellipsis.
It creates a copy of the original, even if the original is destroyed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign()` but be aware of browser support.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign.

Example:

```
myObjTwo = Object.assign({}, myObjOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line `myObjTwo = myObjOne` does not clone `myObjOne`, it just creates a duplicate reference to the same object!

The actual answer is to use a clone function, perhaps from a library such as [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#clone).  But really, it looks like you have some reading and learning to do about the concept of objects and pointers in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

```
var clone=function(o){
      var n= {}.toString.apply(o)=="[object Array]" ? []:{};
      for(i in o)
         n[i]= typeof o[i]=='object' ? clone(o[i]):o[i];
      return n;
 };
```

Usage:

```
var x={a:{d:34},b:33};
var y=clone(x);  // clones 'x'
```