# Why this Javascript Object not change..?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I copy the object and change the property,

it seems the property has been change, but the object not change:

```
var partCp = myDoorObj['part'][0];
for (var i = 0; i < doorCount; i++) {

    partCp['var']['no'] = i + 1;
    partCp['var']['_name'] = 'door' + (i + 1);

    console.log(partCp);
    console.log(partCp['var']['_name']);

    myDoorObj['part'].push(partCp);

}
```

with the console log:

[image]

`partCp['var']['_name']` has been change,  but `partCp` object in the console are same..

so whats the problem??

Comment: `=` copies the reference only.  Did you mean to make a deep copy? You possibly need some recursion to do that, underscore.js provides a suitable deepcopy.

Comment: @chanjianyi If you don't get an answer then just thank Juhana.

Comment: Juhanas point is that there is a known bug where you can't trust th e console to log objects as they were.  Also, though, the OP says he copies an object when only the reference is copied.

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing the same object twice. JavaScript arrays store objects by reference; both of them now refer to the same object. However, you are also using a [browser that suffers from a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays) that the objects written to `console.log` are not displayed until after a while, and thus the value shown there is not the value of the object upon the time of `console.log` but some point of time afterwards.

However, your code is still buggy.

`partCp` refers here to the same object all the time; you first change that object's `number` to `1` and `name` to `door1`, then push; and after that you change the same object's `number` to `2` and `name` to `door2`, and push a reference to that object again; as there was only 1 object to begin with, both elements of the array are references to the same object. Now, the *browser bug made you post a question*, but on a working browser, if you do `console.log(myDoorObj['part'])` you would see that there still are `door2`s in the array.

To construct a new copy of the `partCp`, see 
[Javascript - How to clone an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965822/javascript-how-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: But the object is sent to the console *before* it's changed. The issue is with how Chrome queues messages sent to the console, not with object properties.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to solve the problem...

```
var partCp = jQuery.extend(true, {}, myDoorObj['part'][0]);

for (var i = 0; i < doorCount; i++) {

    var tempPartCp = jQuery.extend(true, {}, partCp);

    tempPartCp['var']['no'] = i + 1;
    tempPartCp['var']['_name'] = 'door' + (i + 1);

    console.log(tempPartCp);
    console.log(tempPartCp['var']['_name']);

    myDoorObj['part'].push(tempPartCp);

}
```